# How do you set a Class's attribute using only a String?

Tags: flutter, dart

So I recently started learning Dart to use with flutter and found the class method `get` that resembles python's `__getattr__` method and was wondering if there is the same thing for `set`. I know set exists but I've only seen it used for a already known attribute name.

```dart
// example of what I'm looking for
MyClass mc = MyClass();
print(mc.anything123);  // return's `null` because it does not exist in the map
mc.anything123 = 'some value';
print(mc.anything123);  // return's `'some value'`
```

my current code [update: ignore this code, it is incorrect. but I'll still leave it here]:

```dart
// class MyClass {
//   Map<String, dynamic> data;

//   MyClass({required this.data});
  

//   dynamic get(String propertyName) {
//     var _mapRep = data;
//     if (_mapRep.containsKey(propertyName)) {
//       return _mapRep[propertyName];
//     }
//     return null;
//   }

//   // set(String propertyName, dynamic value) {...}
// }

// MyClass globalValues = MyClass(data: {});

// MyClass MyClassState() {
//   return globalValues;
// }
```

Update:

As pointed out in the comment's the above code isn't working. I'm not sure what I had on friday that was giving null values. I'll chalk it up to only 2 day's of Dart experience. But still, having methods like python's `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` would be a dream come true.

Comment: You can't create an instance like `MyClass mc = MyClass();` according to your class's constructor definition. You can create  like `get(key)` while key will be needed

Comment: "and found the class method `get`..." You didn't *find* anything.  You created an ordinary method named `get`.  You could have named it whatever you want. (`get` is probably a bad name since [`get` is keyword](https://dart.dev/language/keywords) that sometimes has a special meaning, but not in this case.)

Comment: (resisting the urge to demonstrate that this might be somewhat possible using an Expando....)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your purpose, you like to set value with will be normal method like

```dart
class MyClass {
  Map<String, dynamic> data;

  MyClass({this.data = const {}});

  void set(String propertyName, dynamic value) {
    data[propertyName] = value;
  }

  dynamic get(String propertyName) {
    if (data.containsKey(propertyName)) {
      return data[propertyName];
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

But as for the getter and setter

```dart
class Foo {
  Map<String, dynamic> _data = {};
  set a(Map<String, dynamic> value) {
    _data = value;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> get data => _data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I upvoted the answer because it's very helpful in my circumstance. I decided not to mark it just because my question(though somewhat wrong) was trying to duplicate python's `__getattr__` and `__setattr__`. That seems like StackOverflow's way of doing things, although let me know if anyone disagrees.